# mySQL Search Engine still not getting the relationships right for multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

The following SQL query in PHP should display results based on title and tag entries. The tags are located in the table wp_terms and the posts in wp_posts. In the middle we have wp_term_relationships to link everything up.

In `wp_posts` the  field we want is `post_id`
In `wp_term_relationships` the field `object_id` should match the post id and `term_taxonomy_id` should match the `term_id`.
In `wp_terms` the `term_id` should match the `term_taxonomy_id` in `wp_terms_relationships`. Then we want the field from `wp_terms` called `name` for the purpose of the search.

At the moment this code is not including terms in the search.

```
SELECT ID, post_name, post_title, post_date 
FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_term_relationships 
ON        object_id = wp_posts.id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms 
ON        term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 

WHERE 
wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%$my_text%' OR wp_terms.name LIKE '%$my_text%')"
```

How do we get this one working.

**UPDATE**

What is supposed to happen is the search is supposed to return results based on post title or post tag. The problem is post tags are considered terms and help in another table that requires a third to find the corresponding id.

I will try and map the relevant but.

```
TABLE:  wp_posts

==================================================================
    post_id       ====     post_title
==================================================================

TABLE wp_terms

==================================================================
        term_id       ====     name
==================================================================

TABLE wp_term_relationships

==================================================================
        object_id       ====     term_taxonomy_id
==================================================================
```

So we use wp_term_relationships to get which term id's (`term_taxonomy_id`) reflect which posts (`object_id`);

Hope that helps

**Table Structure Image**

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what needs to happen without seeing your database schema.

Comment: I edited my post, I'm not sure if you also would like to get the name(s) of each tag for the retrieved post? But you can try the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but if you like to get the name of associated terms then this will work:

```
$query = 
 "SELECT DISTINCT ID, post_name, post_title, post_date
  FROM wp_posts 
  JOIN wp_term_relationships 
  ON object_id = wp_posts.id
  LEFT JOIN wp_terms 
  ON term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
  WHERE 
  wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
  AND (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%$my_text%' OR wp_terms.name LIKE '%$my_text%')";
```

Comment: Effective but with a few failings. It is only picking up one post if it is by tag only rather than as many as there may be, and two it is picking up multiple versions of the same post if the keyword is in both the title and tag